# Azure Iot Hub Device to Cloud Communication with Backend

Tags: asp.net, azure, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-iot-hub

Hi i already have cloud to device communication through Direct Methods. Now I want to setup Device to Backend Communication through Iot Hub , I have read we can do this with device to cloud communication but is there any way we can route these messages to backend app that is my web api.

Comment: Hi @Usman Khalid , if the responses below answered your question can you mark as answer to help community as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way we can route these messages to backend app that is my web api.

Your app can consume the messages directly using the [EventHub APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/iothub-connect-to-eventhubs/), or create an [Azure Function with an Event Hub Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).

Comment: so i have to deploy separate console application to listen to event hub?

Comment: You can do it from your main application if you want.

Comment: my main application is dot net core web api application,is there any way to setup in this application.

Comment: You can have long-running Background tasks in your .NET Core API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David's answer, the following screen snippet shows forwarding a telemetry data to the *Web App* using the *Azure Event Grid* (*Push-Push Pattern*) with different subscribers such as the *Hybrid Connection*, *WeebHook* and *EventGridTrigger* function with a SignalR Service output binding:

[image]